# How can I index a custom column in SharePoint 2010 FAST search?

Tags: crawling, fast-search, index

I am using sharepoint 2010. I have created a document library. Inside this library I am using a custom content type. In this content type I have 3 custom columns like (Company name, Company address, Company number). I have filled my library with some dummy data. When I try to search inside my library on the title of the document I got results. So the Title column is crawled/indexed. But when I try to search on "Company name" I dont have search results.

Do I need to make this column crawlable/indexable? How can I also search on my custom columns like "Company name"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the corresponding `ows_ColumnName` crawled property and make sure the crawled property has `IsMappedToContents` set to true.

Once re-crawled the contents of this column/crawled property should be searchable from the full-text index.

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393801(v=office.14).aspx